# Why does this loop end up reversing the array?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, iterator

```cs
/*
         Given an array of ints length 3, return an array with the elements "rotated left" so {1, 2, 3}
         yields {2, 3, 1}.
         RotateLeft3([1, 2, 3]) → [2, 3, 1]
         RotateLeft3([5, 11, 9]) → [11, 9, 5]
         RotateLeft3([7, 0, 0]) → [0, 0, 7]
         */
        public int[] RotateLeft3(int[] nums)
        {
            int temp = nums[0];

            for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length -1; i++)
            {
                nums[i] = nums[i + 1];
            }

            nums[nums.Length - 1] = temp;

            return nums;
        }
```

This is an exercise question that I'm having trouble translating into plain English, I'm not following how this ends up rotating* the array after the loop finishes.

Comment: Maybe you better re-read the description you posted...  Who says it reverses the array?  That's not what the comment says it does.

Comment: Maybe "shift left" would be better description instead of "rotate left"

Comment: @RandRandom In assembly, 'shift left' means losing the leftmost bit, whereas 'rotate left' means add the leftmost bit to the righthand side, so in this case, calling the function RotateLeft is correct.

Answer (score 2):

This is not reversing the array. It is shifting all the entries to the left one, and wrapping the first element back to the end of the array.

- The first operation saves the first item.
- The for loop takes each item and copies the next item over the top of it.
- The last operation puts the saved first item over top the last item.

Answer (score 1):

The code as posted appears to be rotating the values through the array.

Translating it into words,

1. Remember the first item
2. Move the second item into the first position, 3rd into 2nd etc (repeat for all remaining items)
3. Put the remembered item in the last position.

It doesn't appear to 'reverse' the array.